# WPF Conversion from SystemParameter units to Device-Independent Units

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make an application that will take up the maximum amount of workarea on screen other than the titlebar and the taskbar.

I cannot use the WindowState.Maximize property in Xaml because I have a linkedbox that has generated buttons based on items in a configuration file.

My question is, since SystemParameter.WorkArea.Height/Width give me the measurements in pixels, but Height in XAML expects the measurement in DIU(DIP) Device-Independent Units. Is there a way to convert between the two?

At the moment when I set the window size to the system.parameter resolution it does not cover the entire working area and leaves a small strip uncovered, which I assume is some Windows 10 area used for resizing or letting the user perform other functions I do not need.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
public double DipsToPixelsX(double input)
{
    return input * PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.Windows[0]).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
}

public double DipsToPixelsY(double input)
{
    return input * PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.Windows[0]).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
}

public double PixelsToDipsX(double input)
{
    return input / PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.Windows[0]).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
}

public double PixelsToDipsY(double input)
{
    return input / PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.Windows[0]).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I am trying to get the height and width to create the window. I cannot read the dpi after the MainWindow has been loaded because nothing has been loaded when I need to call the functions.

Comment: Ok, I have changed MainWindow to Windows[0]. Windows[0] can be accessed before the main window has been loaded. I've tried this on the Window_Loaded event, and the window's height and width can be adjusted using Windows[0] in that event before the main window has been loaded.